# NextJS image module not found

Tags: next.js

Im new to NextJS. Im very confused about images. I get the below error. I followed the documentation for the npm next-image but I still cant display the image

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages({
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```

Comment: What line/file is triggering that error?

Answer (score 1):

check your next version in package.json, if it is more than 10, you don't need any third-party libraries

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure to create a file called next.config.js in the root project directory. and place this inside

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages();
```